# Size of array doubling when using "in range"

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a code that opens sample and background data (10^5 points each) and subtracts one from the other. When running the code for the first time, it works flawlessly. However, when I remove the background data and choose another file for the background, the subtraction is not performed. I found it is due to the doubling of the sample array size when executing the "subtract_bkgr_from_magn" command. What happens is that before "for i in range" the size is 100000 points but immediately after this command it becomes 200000. There's obviously something going on that I am not aware of. Could someone explain to me what is wrong with my code and how it could be rectified?

```
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

top = Tk.Tk()

class Window:

    def __init__(self):
        self.top = top
        self.m = []
        self.m_bkgr = []
        self.m_true = []
        Tk.Button(top, text='Sample', command=self.open_sample, width=10).pack()
        Tk.Button(top, text='X', command=self.remove_bkgr).pack()
        Tk.Button(top, text='Background', command=self.open_bkgr, width=10).pack()
        Tk.Button(top, text='Calculate', command=self.calculate, width=7).pack()

    def openfile(self):
        self.opfi = askopenfilename()

    def calc_file_length(self):
        with open(self.opfi, 'r') as file:
            for i, l in enumerate(file):
                pass
        self.number = i + 1

    def open_sample(self):
        self.openfile()
        self.calc_file_length()

    def open_bkgr(self):
        self.opbkgr = askopenfilename()

    def empty_arrays(self):
        del self.m[:], self.m_bkgr[:], self.m_true[:]

    def columns_for_sample(self):
        with open(self.opfi, 'r') as file:
            for line in range(self.number):
                g = file.readline().split('\t')
                if line >= 7:
                    self.magn = str(g[5])
                    self.m.append(eval(self.magn))

    def column_for_bkgr(self):
        if self.opbkgr:
            with open(self.opbkgr, 'r') as file:
                for line in range(self.number):
                    w = file.readline().split('\t')
                    if line >= 7:
                        self.magn_bkgr = str(w[5])
                        self.m_bkgr.append(eval(self.magn_bkgr))
        else: # no background
            pass

    def subtract_bkgr_from_magn(self):
        if self.opbkgr:
            for i in range(len(self.m)):
                self.m_true.append(self.m[i] - self.m_bkgr[i])
        else: # no background
            self.m_true = self.m

    def calculate(self):
        self.empty_arrays()
        self.columns_for_sample()
        self.column_for_bkgr()
        self.subtract_bkgr_from_magn()

    def remove_bkgr(self):
        self.opbkgr = ''
        del self.m_bkgr[:]

a = Window()

Tk.mainloop()
```

Here's a sample of the data I work with (they are similar for the sample and background):

```
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
-0.003333   -0.133333   0.010000    -0.133333   0.003333    0.000250
-0.016667   -0.100000   0.003333    0.000000    0.002083    -0.000208
0.003333    -0.066667   0.010000    -0.133333   0.002083    -0.000208
-0.003333   -0.066667   0.016667    -0.133333   0.002500    -0.000125
-0.003333   -0.100000   0.010000    -0.333333   0.003750    4.166667E-5
-0.003333   -0.066667   0.010000    -0.266667   0.002500    0.000375
-0.003333   -0.066667   0.003333    -0.133333   0.002917    0.000667
```

Comment: `self.m_true = self.m` is binding `m_true` to `m`. I suggest `self.m_true[:] = self.m`

Comment: Looks like I should learn how to do the copying properly in Python :-)